# Openlayers image over standard map

Tags: openlayers

I'm building a new mapping application. However, we need to be able to overlay a tif file (for which we have coordinates to place it using OL bounds) over a map of the US/world. The tif file only covers about 20 kilometers or something so it's not very big. I so far have created a map element with just the tif file and I can pan/zoom etc on the tif, but I want to have the normal map behind it so that when the user pans out of the tif area, they see the regular map. Can anyone point me to some examples?

Comment: Have you had time to look at my suggestion?

Comment: I have. I got it working, but the image is so large that it's really killing the browser. I'd love to find a way to make that more efficient, but the user needs to be able to update that image overlay periodically, so doing a tile option isn't really feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Layer.Image](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html) object. Positions an image as a layer, and if you put that on top of a base map, it should do what you want.